# How to compile custom format ini file with redirects?

Tags: parsing, pseudocode, ini

I'm working with an application that has 3 ini files in a somewhat irritating custom format. I'm trying to compile these into a 'standard' ini file.

I'm hoping for some inspiration in the form of pseudocode to help me code some sort of 'compiler'.

Here's an example of one of these ini files. The less than/greater than indicates a redirect to another section in the file. These redirects could be recursive.. i.e. one redirect then redirects to another. It could also mean a redirect to an external file (3 values are present in that case). Comments start with a # symbol

```
[PrimaryServer]
name = DEMO1
baseUrl = http://demo1.awesome.com    

[SecondaryServer]
name = DEMO2
baseUrl = http://demo2.awesome.com

[LoginUrl]
# This is a standard redirect
baseLoginUrl = <PrimaryServer:baseUrl>

# This is a redirect appended with extra information
fullLoginUrl = <PrimaryServer:baseUrl>/login.php

# Here's a redirect that points to another redirect
enableSSL = <SSLConfiguration:enableSSL>

# This is a key that has mutliple comma-separated values, some of which are redirects.
serverNames = <PrimaryServer:name>,<SecondaryServer:name>,AdditionalRandomServerName

# This one is particularly nasty. It's a redirect to another file...
authenticationMechanism = <Authenication.ini:Mechanisms:PrimaryMechanism>

[SSLConfiguration]
enableSSL = <SSLCertificates:isCertificateInstalled>

[SSLCertificates]
isCertificateInstalled = true
```

Here's an example of what I'm trying to achieve. I've removed the comments for readability.

```
[PrimaryServer]
name = DEMO1
baseUrl = http://demo1.awesome.com

[SecondaryServer]
name = DEMO2
baseUrl = http://demo2.awesome.com

[LoginUrl]
baseLoginUrl = http://demo1.awesome.com

fullLoginUrl = http://demo1.awesome.com/login.php

enableSSL = true

serverNames = DEMO1,DEMO2,AdditionalRandomServerName

authenticationMechanism = valueFromExternalFile

[SSLConfiguration]
enableSSL = <SSLCertificates:isCertificateInstalled>

[SSLCertificates]
isCertificateInstalled = true
```

I'm looking at using ini4j (Java) to achieve this, but am by no means fixed on using that language.

My main questions are:

- 1) How can I handle the recursive redirects
- 2) How am I best to handle the redirects that have an additional string, e.g. `serverNames`
- 3) Bonus points for any suggestions about how to handle the external redirects. No big deal if that part isn't working just yet.

So far, I'm able to parse and tidy up the file, but I'm struggling with these redirects.

Once again, I'm only hoping for pseudocode. Perhaps I need more coffee, but I'm really puzzled by this one.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.